# Filesystem access in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, svn

I have Windows 8.1 installed on a VM using virtualbox. My host system is Ubuntu 13.04.

I use windows for testing, and also for tortoiseSVN. For some reason, commiting on tortoise takes way too much time to populate the commit window. Even if I only select one small project, it takes 15-20 second to show the classes that have been changed etc. In the past I was using Parallels for my VM (on a MBP) and that same screen with the same projects would be populated almost instantly.

Anyone is aware of any paramenters that might be affecting the performance? I am giving plenty of hardware resources to the VM ( 6 cores, 4gb ram,256 video/3d ) so that cant be an issue for SVN. Is it possible that the files are accessed through network? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may sound backwards but you often get better performance if you reduce the number of cores on the virtual (guest) CPU.  Giving the guest machine 6 cores you need to wait for all 6 cores to come ready (on the host machine) for every compute cycle.  By reducing to a single core you only need to wait for 1 core to come ready on the host machine.

Comment: I changed to 6 cores while trying to see if that would fix my problem. Originally I had the default setting which is 1 core. Also, this must not be a processing-intensive task.